# LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".so"

Tags: android, android-ndk

when use ndk-r10e to build my project with static library, in the Android.mk, through,

*include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := game-cocos2dx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../AgoraGamingSDK/libs/android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgame-cocos2dx.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)*

But get the error log:

**LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".so"**

Answer (score 0):

Updating ndk to android-ndk-r14b,can make it.